# Database for Quotes needed: Tags, multi-language support?

Tags: database, language, tags

Dear superuser userbase!

Almost every website now supports **tags**. I want to harness the power of tags for a private database, can you help?

**Ideal:** 
A database of quotes (columns: English | German | Spanish | Source | Tags | Comment)
When entering new quotes, it should offer me tags and sources I've already used. 
When browsing quotes, it should offer to filter by tags.
Storage ideally web-based or local on my linux machine.

**Current Status:**
I've used a Google Fusion Table to do the job, only *problem* is that it doesn't understand that I *store multiple tags in one field*.

So if quote A is tagged "inspirational, health" and quote B is tagged "inspirational" there is no way for me to filter my quotes for "inspirational" and make both of them show up.

**Additional research:**

1. With **libreoffice base** there doesn't seem to be a natural way of tagging either.
2. I came across this post http://ask.metafilter.com/243330/The-personal-database-of-the-future that suggests I could use **Evernote** for the job, but I am worried that multi-language support will be tough to realise. And I am on linux so I'd have to use Nixnote.

Comments are much appreciated!

Alex from Germany